# Component is not updating properly in React TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have created a module using typescript which is not updating properly (the value is updating only second time rendering), Can anyone suggest a solution for this issue.

```
handleDisplayName = (evt: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
        const options: UrlSelectorOptions = {
            ...this.props.options,
            displayName: evt.target.value,
        }
        this.props.onOptionsChange({ ...options })
        console.log("Options" + options);

    }
render() {
        return (
            <>
                <label><strong>Display Name</strong></label>
                <input
                    className="input"
                    type="text"
                    value={this.props.options.displayName}
                    onChange={this.handleDisplayName} />
            </>
          }
```

Comment: what `onOptionsChange ` does?

Comment: It's a callback function

Comment: share your code for `onOptionsChange ` please

Comment: export interface PanelEditorProps<T = any> {
    /** Panel options */
    options: T;
    /** Panel options change handler */
    onOptionsChange: (options: T, callback?: () => void) => void;
    /** Result set of panel queries */
    data?: PanelData;
}

Comment: Please edit your question and show more of your code. I'm assuming onOptionsChange function changes the state. There isn't enough to understand your code fully.